# How to Install HP Scanjet 200 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, hp, scanner

Anybody please help me to install this scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the HP Scanjet 200 has no support for Linux. No open-source or proprietary drivers from HP are available.

Source: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Scanning-Faxing-and-Copying/HP-ScanJet-200-Flatbed-Ubuntu-Drivers/td-p/4996953